# Is there any way that I could find out the market share of each miner manufacturer?

Tags: mining-hardware, antminer

I am considering getting into mining myself. And I would like to compare different mining equipments and how many people are using each of the equipment. It seems like it is really hard to find the data on the market share of mining industry. If anyone knows or has any recommendations on which miner would be best for serious miners, please let me know. Thanks :)

Answer (score -1):

I found this site: https://bitcoinwisdom.com/bitcoin/calculator that enables you to input your electrical costs, your computation rate, how much you paid for your mining hardware and the bitcoin value to calculate profitability. there is also: https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Mining_hardware_comparison which is worth a look. I'm hoping to find out if mining is worth it if you cannot make an initial investment over 4-500$. Still working on it, haven't started yet.

Comment: It is not clear to me, whether you are asking a new question or attempting to answer this one. If the latter, your answer appears to miss the main point, as it doesn't address how to find out the market share of different manufacturers.